# (WDS) UEFI PXE Boot Fails While Downloading NBP File

Tags: windows-server-2016, pxe-boot, sccm, wds, uefi

Hello guys i'm currently running into an issue where the laptop that i'm trying to network boot with would go download the NBP file over the network but then it would go back to the BIOS menu. I was following [this](https://www.petri.com/deploy-windows-10-using-mdt-wds-part-1-create-mdt-deployment-share) guide in the process.

as you can see from the screenshot below that once the "*Downloading NBP file...*" appear for sometime, then it would throw me back into the BIOS menu.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh83S.jpg)

**What's Expected:**
the "*Succeed to download NBP file*" message should come up next and then boot into WinPE.

**Environment:**

- HP Elitebook 850 G4 (Laptop to PXE boot) (BIOS Updated)
- Server 1 (WS2016) - DHCP
- Server 2 (WS2016) - Microsoft Deployment Toolkit & Windows Deployment
  Server

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi @hexalogy, I saw `SCCM` in your tag. Are you using SCCM with this environment? I do not remember there being a NBP option with pure MDT and WDS. It should say `Windows is loading files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pxeboot.n12` is a BIOS NBP

`bootmgr.exe` is a BIOS NBP

`bootmgfw.efi` is a UEFI NBP

but

`LiteTouchPE_x64.wim` **is not** an NBP; the PXE firmware will fail trying to directly boot a `wim` file and it would go back trying to boot again...
the booting sequence could be i.e.

pxeboot.n12->bootmgr.exe->LiteTouchPE_x64.wim

Comment: This was it! thanks! had to point it to bootmgfw.efi instead

Answer (score 0):

For the "HP EliteDesk 800 G5" I chose the file `SMSBoot\x64\wdsmgfw.efi` (SCCM 2019)